# How can a ventless (gas) fire box be put in a wall safely?

Tags: fireplace

It (ventless fireplace) is currently sitting on the floor, taking up needed floor space and I would like to have it placed inside the wall? I need to know any and everything that would need to be done to make this possible. Step by step please and thank you.

Comment: I'd get rid of any ventless gas appliance in my house.  Even if the technology works perfectly, there's still a huge amount of vapour produced.  And if the technology fails, and you get a Carbon Monoxide exhaust, you could be dead.

Comment: I agree with @ChrisCudmore but to answer your question, no one here can.  You need to get the documentation for your fire box and see what the requirements and install is they require to meet code.

Comment: In answer to your response either one could cause death. Any wood burning fuel can cause Carbon Monoxide the same as a natural gas ventless or vented fireplaces.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have the ventless appliance, you should have a carbon monoxide (CO) detector in your home. Ideally, there would be more than one per floor with detectors located near the primary inhabited areas.

Under ideal conditions, both propane and natural gas (since you didn't specify) will combust to produce pure water (H2O) and carbon dioxide (CO2). However, this is rarely the case, even in ventless-rated appliances. Typically, the combustion is not ideal, and some small amount of CO is produced, but is not of a level high enough to cause health concerns. Most homes are not 100% air tight and there is enough air exchange to prevent CO build-up.

The largets concern with placing the ventless appliance in the wall is going to be trapping the combustion gases. Trapping the CO can cause a significant build-up of CO in an isolated area which could cause health concerns or even death. Trapping the H2O could provide an enviroment suitable to mold growth which can pose a health hazard.

If you are determined to install this ventless appliance in the wall, you will need to ensure that the appliance receives sufficient intake air to maintain complete, ideal combustion, and that combustion gases are vented into the room rather than into the wall. Whether or not this is possible will depend on where the intake and exhaust vents are located on the ventless appliance.

Please consult the owner's manual for any warnings before doing any work or modifcations.

Comment: Thank you rjbergen for responding to my question.  I do have CO detectors.  The firebox will be installed in an outside wall. I have used my fireplace for many years and have had no problems because as you stated most houses are not 100 airtight and I always keep a window cracked where it is located to prevent Any CO buildup. It is natural gas. If any problems do occur the fireplace logs automatically cut off.

Comment: Thank you RJBergen for responding. My ventless fireplace is natural gas. The firebox will be inserted on an outside wall. So the actual firebox will protrude on the outside of the house. I do have CO detectors. And for safety precautions I keep a window slightly cracked during use. I hope this explains what I am attempting to do a little better.

Comment: It sounds like you have the CO aspect covered by cracking a window, having CO detectors, and having a self-regulating ventless appliance. My primary concern in that situation based on your usage would be to prevent moisture build-up in the wall cavity that could lead to mold. Without knowing anything about the appliance's venting method, I can't tell you how to prevent the moisture build-up. It's possible that the device exhausts from the front and it's simple, but if it exhausts eleswhere you'll have to work around that.

Comment: Yes, it exhaust from the front. Would the casing or wood and insulation that would go around the firebox prevent molding?

Comment: If it vents from the front, you shouldn't see any appreciable moisture build up in the wall cavity. I would say that you are able to recess it into the wall in this case.